# OpenVPN eth0 rejects ping

Tags: 16.04, vpn, openvpn, routing, ping

I have installed OpenVPN server in one Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I need to connect from outside my home with OpenVPN clients

***Ping from server(192.168.2.50) using tun0 network works***

**Client-1**

```
vino@ubuntu:~$ ping 10.8.0.18    
PING 10.8.0.18 (10.8.0.18) 56(84) bytes of data.    
64 bytes from 10.8.0.18: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=240 ms    
64 bytes from 10.8.0.18: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=47.0 ms    
^C    
--- 10.8.0.18 ping statistics ---    
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms    
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 47.020/143.818/240.617/96.799 ms
```

**Client-2**

```
vino@ubuntu:~$ ping 10.8.0.22    
PING 10.8.0.22 (10.8.0.22) 56(84) bytes of data.    
64 bytes from 10.8.0.22: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=217 ms    
64 bytes from 10.8.0.22: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=589 ms    
64 bytes from 10.8.0.22: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=507 ms    
^C    
--- 10.8.0.22 ping statistics ---    
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms    
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 217.640/438.043/589.171/159.390 ms
```

***But ping from server using eth0 and wlp4s0 network fails***

**Client-1**

```
vino@ubuntu:~$ ping 192.168.1.5    
PING 192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.5) 56(84) bytes of data.    
^C    
--- 192.168.1.5 ping statistics ---    
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1000ms
```

**Client-2**

```
vino@ubuntu:~$ ping 192.168.43.253    
PING 192.168.43.253 (192.168.43.253) 56(84) bytes of data.    
^C    
--- 192.168.43.253 ping statistics ---    
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5020ms
```

**I cannot able to ping using wlp3n0 or eth0 networks from server to client and vice-versa**